# changed default gcc version, now compiling problems

Tags: c++, node.js, gcc, atom-editor

For an installation I had to change my default gcc compiler version. I had some compilation issues with the version I used so I downloaded several other versions via macports, and one of them worked for my installation finally.

I'm almost sure that the one I used before was gcc4.2, listed in my ports as: llvm-gcc42 .

In two other cases now I  am facing compilation problems of c++ files. I'm not knowledgeable with c++, I'm using the compiler just for the compilation of some - mostly node.js - modules or now, a package for the atom editor.

Here is what I get, that leads me to the assumtion that something with the c++ compiler is not correct:

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"

I could get rid of this in the first case by changing the default gcc version. But I cannot try several versions everytime.

So: Which is the gcc version I should use or is there anything else that could cause this? gcc5, the latest gives me the same..

---

**In a specific case: Problem with installing termrk (module for the atom editor)**

```
gcc --version
gcc (MacPorts gcc5 5.2.0_0) 5.2.0
[...]
```

There are two ways to install atom packages: Inside the editor with the gui and with the command line tool apm. Neither one works, but I get different error messages.

*1. inside the gui:*

```html
> pty.js@0.2.13 install /private/var/folders/nl/2ppbw8fn0cjbw04pdqbxmqtr0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-115913-1105-1g6fykw/node_modules/Termrk/node_modules/pty.js
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.6.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/nl/2ppbw8fn0cjbw04pdqbxmqtr0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-115913-1105-1g6fykw/node_modules/Termrk/node_modules/pty.js
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 12.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/Users/michael/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/Users/michael/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/private/var/folders/nl/2ppbw8fn0cjbw04pdqbxmqtr0000gn/T/d-115913-1105-1hg4ytj/package.tgz" "--target=0.30.7" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pty.js@0.2.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pty.js@0.2.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the pty.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/nl/2ppbw8fn0cjbw04pdqbxmqtr0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-115913-1105-1g6fykw/npm-debug.log
```

*1. In the terminal:*

```html
~ michael$ sudo apm install termrk
Installing termrk to /Users/michael/.atom/packages ✗

> pty.js@0.2.13 install /private/tmp/apm-install-dir-115913-1063-2zj63h/node_modules/Termrk/node_modules/pty.js
> node-gyp rebuild


shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied

node.js:844
    var cwd = process.cwd();
                      ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied
    at Function.startup.resolveArgv0 (node.js:844:23)
    at startup (node.js:58:13)
    at node.js:935:3
npm ERR! Darwin 12.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/Users/michael/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/Users/michael/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/private/tmp/d-115913-1063-1cgkfyq/package.tgz" "--target=0.30.7" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pty.js@0.2.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pty.js@0.2.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the pty.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/tmp/apm-install-dir-115913-1063-2zj63h/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I think I'll remove my answer because it actually makes little sense. Seems like node-gyp picks up the old version of the compiler. I have no knowledge about it and will be of no help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid option for GCC 5.2 so if it says it's unrecognized then it means you are not using GCC 5.2.

You're probably still compiling with the old GCC 4.2 version.

Comment: makes sense, but gcc --version tells me gcc (MacPorts gcc5 5.2.0_0) 5.2.0 . Any idea how to check if node-gyp uses the right version?